# Enthuware Mock-20 Confusion -classpath and packages

Tags: java, classpath

I am using enthuware to practice mock questions for classpath and packages. Here is the question.

```
//in file ./Foo.java
public class Foo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("In Foo");
  } 
}

//in file ./com/Foo.java
package com;
public class Foo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("In com.Foo");
  } 
}

Which of the given statements are correct assuming that the command lines are executed from the current directory with default classpath set to ./classes?
```

The options given are

1. Executing java -classpath .:./com Foo will print "In com.Foo"
2. Executing java -classpath ./com:. Foo will print "In com.Foo"
3. Executing java Foo will print "In com.Foo"
4. java -classpath . com.Foo will not execute.
5. Executing java -classpath ./com:. com.Foo will print "In com.Foo"

Correct option given is option-5. The strange problem is when i try to execute option-5 from my command line it gives me the following error.
[image: Option-5 Execution Error]

Can someone tell me what is wrong? I am not able to figure out the reason. Plus what does this
`./com` classpath mean?

**Command Change**

I noticed one strange thing, if i change the classpath and run the command as

```
java -classpath . com.Foo
```

It states `in com.Foo`. As soon as i change the command to add this path ./com. It gives the above mentioned error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The "./com" is a relative path to the current path.

If you have your class in [current_path]/com/Foo.class

You can run your class with the following command:

```
 java -classpath ./com com.Foo
```

If you are in the com folder [current_path: com]/Foo.class you can execute the following command:

```
java -classpath . com.Foo
```